# Black Shadow showing on object in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image]

There are black shadows/lines on the axle and the side (both pictured). This only shows in rendered view, and once I put the project into Cycles from EEVEE.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think it is hard to solve that problems without the blend file.

Comment: @XY [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=z7MK6ZsR" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/z7MK6ZsR/)  link to file

Comment: I suspect overlapping meshes.